# Sublime Text Search and Insert Content within Quotes

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Original:

```
description: Hello World
description: Hello India
description: Hello Guys
```

I have 20000 lines of this in a yaml file, i want to search and put the content of **description** in **double quotes**, the **content of description varies every line**

I want:

```
description: "Hello World"
description: "Hello India"
description: "Hello Guys"
```

So is this thing doable, if yes, then can you suggest me how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with find and replace (menu: find/replace).
In the find box type:

```
description: (.*)
```

In the replace box:

```
description: "$1"
```

Then press *replace*.

Remember to select the "regular expression" box:

[image]